# Algorithm to detect if a period of time is not covered by other periods

Tags: java

My goal is fairly simple : I have a list of object with an end date and a start date. I need to find the uncovered periods, and create a new object from those (with a start date at day + 1 and an end date at day -1 for each hole found).

Let's say I've got 6 objects in my first list as follows :

Object 1 :
`start-date : 2022-01-01 / end-date 2022-01-03`

Object 2 :
`start-date : 2022-01-08/ end-date 2022-01-18`

Object 3 :
`start-date : 2022-02-11 / end-date 2022-02-19`

Object 4 :
`start-date : 2022-02-22 / end-date 2022-02-25`

Object 5 :
`start-date : 2022-02-17 / end-date 2022-03-10`

Object 6 :
`start-date : 2022-03-18 / end-date 2022-03-25`

I would need to generate the three following objects :

First period :
`start-date : 2022-01-04 / end-date 2022-01-07`

Second period :
`start-date : 2022-01-19 / end-date 2022-02-10`

Three period :
`start-date : 2022-03-11 / end-date 2022-03-17`

How do you think I should go about it, using Java 8 and `LocalDate` objects ?

Comment: this problem seems identical to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/),might help :)

Comment: Note that an algorithm won't particularly care about which data types you use, it would be a description of "which steps, in which order, given which inputs, are necessary to perform the task". Only the _implementation_ of it would be "java" relevant (and require java classes). So the question's kind of "what are you actually asking for?" If you want to know which algorithms exist for interval merging, that's pretty much covered by the internet already (searching will find lots of results). If you want to know how to implement one of those in java, then update your post a little to cover that.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `Period` object which implements the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface to order an `ArrayList<Period>` by `startDate`.

```
public class Period implements Comparable {
  LocalDate startDate;
  LocalDate endDate;
  //getters and setters, constructors, toString...
  public int compareTo(Object obj) { //override
    //type checks...
    return this.startDate.compareTo(((Period) obj).getStartDate());
  }
}
```

Then I would cycle through the ordered list to find if there are holes:

```
public static ArrayList<Period> findHoles(ArrayList<Period> periods) {
  Collections.sort(periods); //if it isn't ordered
  ArrayList<Period> holes = new ArrayList<>();
  Period currentPeriod = periods.get(0);
  for (Period period : periods) {
    LocalDate holeStart = currentPeriod.getEndDate().plusDays(1);
    LocalDate holeEnd = period.getStartDate().minusDays(1);
    if (holeStart.isBefore(holeEnd) || holeStart.isEqual(holeEnd)) {
      holes.add(new Period(holeStart,holeEnd));
    }
    if (currentPeriod.getEndDate().isBefore(period.getEndDate())) {
      currentPeriod = period;
    }
  }
  return holes;
}
```